# what is this line doing in this .htaccess file and do the other lines in this file look safe?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Our site was hacked recently, and is serving files that look like this:

```
www.example.com/some-spam-name
```

These paths are redirecting to some spam affiliate page. 
There are thousands of them.

I've started investigating, and the first thing I have checked is the `.htaccess` file:

It looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^secraksj$ "https\:\/\/example\.karansv\.com\/a\/3845\/RFcFd3FM" [R=301,L]


RewriteOptions inherit

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The obvious thing that stands out is:

```
  RewriteRule ^secraksj$ "https\:\/\/example\.karansv\.com\/a\/3845\/RFcFd3FM" [R=301,L]
```

Can someone explain what this is doing, I can see the regex, `^secraksj$` but don't quite understand how this rewrite is operating.

If I remove the line in question from the `.htaccess` file, do you think the rest of the file looks fairly standard? I'm trying to take things one step at a time, and right now I'm trying to fix the `.htaccess` file.

I would like to know if I remove this line, if you can see anything else in the .htaccess file that an attacker might be using to exploit the site.

I found this: 
[My site was hacked, htaccess file compromised, what should it look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465997/my-site-was-hacked-htaccess-file-compromised-what-should-it-look-like)

But the syntax is different in this `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^secraksj$ "https\:\/\/exampledomain\.karansv\.com\/a\/3845\/RFcFd3FM" [R=301,L]
> ```

This redirects requests for `example.com/secraksj` to `https://example.karansv.com/a/3845/RFcFd3FM`.

Whilst `^secraksj$` is a "regex", it only matches the literal string "secraksj".

And the preceding `RewriteCond` directives simply make sure that the redirect only occurs when accessing the `example.com` host (and no other parked/addon domain).

> do you think the rest of the file looks fairly standard?

Yes, except for the `RewriteOptions inherit` directive. This might be OK, but do you specifically need this? This *inherits* mod_rewrite directives from any parent config file.

The remainder of the `.htaccess` file is a standard (WordPress) front controller pattern.

> But the syntax is different in this `RewriteRule`.

The directives in the linked question aren't actually valid, so I wouldn't use those directives as a reference.

Comment: That's useful to know thanks. Now I'm wondering how this one rewrite is somehow connected to the thousands of spam paths off exampledomain.com that are not that literal string.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? This redirect is probably just one redirect in a chain of redirects from multiple hacked sites. The end goal is probably to get the user to a malicious site (that tries to download a virus, spam, etc???) The idea of multiple redirects is simply to mask the malicious destination.

Comment: Our site has thousands of paths like this Oursite.com/spam-path  showing in Google, that are all redirecting to the same affiliate spam page, I think this line has something to do with it

Comment: Presumably you are doing a `site:` search? These URLs are unlikely to be returned in a _normal_ Google search (since they are simply redirected). However, there are probably other (hacked) sites that are linking/redirecting to the "spam-path" on your site. The best you can do is remove all these redirects and make sure they return a 404 (or preferably 410 to speed up de-indexing).